# Only run build event if a unit test did not initiate the build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, build

I have post-build event steps in my c# class library project that I would rather skip if the build occurred due to the run of a unit test. Is there a way to tell via a macro?

My backup option is to create a separate build configuration, but this would be cumbersome.

Comment: Yes, create different configurations and use `$(ConfigurationName)` in post build events